# Issue with Tkinter: I try to combine a button check with an "insert into textbox"-command. And it does not work

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a simple text-generator framework, which an employer could use to send out rejection letter.

My plan goes as follows:

1. Check/Uncheck a button
2. If button checked: return String 1
   If button not checked: return String 2
3. When "Generate Text" button is cklicked insert String 1 / String 2 into empty textbox.

Of course it does not work, because the String I want is not returned. It inserts stuff into the textbox though and I don't know what else to do. Can somebody please help me out here?

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Rejection Letter Builder - TY, FU, Bye!")
window.configure(background="lightblue")

rejection_text_box = Text(window, width=60, height=40, borderwidth=3)
rejection_text_box.pack()  


email_text = "Hallo"
reapply_text = "\n\nPlease don't be disappointed. Feel free, to reapply!"
not_reapply_text ="Please don't reapply"


def reapply_button_check():
    if reapply_boolean.get():
        print("reapply checked")
        return(reapply_text)
    else:
        print("reapply button not checked")
        return(not_reapply_text)


reapply_boolean=IntVar()
Checkbutton(window, text = "Ask to Reapply", variable=reapply_boolean, onvalue=1, 
            offvalue=0, command=reapply_button_check).pack()  


def press_generate_text_button():
    rejection_text_box.delete(0.0, "end")
    rejection_text_box.insert(1.0, email_text)
    rejection_text_box.insert(2.0, reapply_button_check)
    #### reapply_button_check ist supposed to return a string
    #### and insert it into the text_box


text_generator_button = Button(window, text = "PRESS TO GENERATE \nTEXT", 
    command = lambda: 
        [
            press_generate_text_button(),
            reapply_button_check(),
         ])
text_generator_button.pack()  


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently not calling the function. You need to call the function:

```py
...
def press_generate_text_button():
    rejection_text_box.delete("0.0", "end")
    rejection_text_box.insert("1.0", email_text)
    rejection_text_box.insert("2.0", reapply_button_check())
...
```

*notice the parentheses after `reapply_button_check`*

### Complete code

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Rejection Letter Builder - TY, FU, Bye!")
window.configure(background="lightblue")

rejection_text_box = Text(window, width=60, height=40, borderwidth=3)
rejection_text_box.pack()  


email_text = "Hallo"
reapply_text = "\n\nPlease don't be disappointed. Feel free, to reapply!"
not_reapply_text ="Please don't reapply"


def reapply_button_check():
    if reapply_boolean.get():
        print("reapply checked")
        return(reapply_text)
    else:
        print("reapply button not checked")
        return(not_reapply_text)


reapply_boolean=IntVar()
Checkbutton(window, text = "Ask to Reapply", variable=reapply_boolean, onvalue=1, 
            offvalue=0, command=reapply_button_check).pack()  


def press_generate_text_button():
    rejection_text_box.delete("0.0", "end")
    rejection_text_box.insert("1.0", email_text)
    rejection_text_box.insert("2.0", reapply_button_check())
    #### reapply_button_check ist supposed to return a string
    #### and insert it into the text_box


text_generator_button = Button(window, text = "PRESS TO GENERATE \nTEXT", 
    command = lambda: 
        [
            press_generate_text_button(),
            reapply_button_check(),
         ])
text_generator_button.pack()  


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I have been trying to fix this for the last three hours.... Oh my... Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that `0.0` is not a proper text widget index. Neither is `1.0` and `2.0`. Indexes are strings, and the first character is the string `"1.0"` (lines start counting at 1, characters at 0)

Comment: Bryan makes a good point, indexes should be strings. Fixed the code.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to confirm, because I am not sure if I understand the issue correctly? @SylvesterKruin

Comment: @yam_yam_popcorn Your issue was that, you weren't calling your function. Resulting in passing the function itself to the `insert` method rather than passing the value returned by function.
See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) in case you need any further info on that.

Comment: Thank you for the link! (bookmarked) everything works smoothly so far. :)